# Mac > Microsoft Word 2011 > changes shape color against my will

Tags: macos, colors, microsoft-word-2011

Do this...

1. create a new Word doc
2. draw a shape
3. remove all formatting from it except a single flat color
4. go to fill color in the ribbon & choose the "More Colors" option
5. bring up the "RGB Sliders" in the resulting picker
6. enter "243974" in the "Hex Color #" box & click OK
7. now, when you go back to the same RGB/Hex color picker for that shape, you'll see that Word has CHANGED the color!

i've had a friend confirm this also happens in MS 2008 version.

does ANYBODY understand why it's doing this???!

does ANYBODY know how to FIX this & keep it from happening???!

here are some screenshots to show what is happening...

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Comment: Inlined your images. You've been a member on SO for more than 3 years, so surely you know the restrictions on low-rep users?

Comment: @Karan, thank you for doing that. honestly, i don't "get" some of the rules for Stack___ sites. but to be fair, i have never found the time/energy to read thru all the info about them. but it has been very frustrating having to "learn the hard way" :-)